# EasyNetQ handle manual ack

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm running a service (multiple instances) to consume messages in RabbitMQ using easynetQ.

I want to check if the message is already being received to the instance 1 and if it cannot process in instance 1, instance 1 should should consume the message and it should enqueue. So it should be consumed by instance 2 and try to process the message. I'm thinking of manual ack of the message.

Is there any possibility of achieving this using EasyNetQ? or any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is more a question of how the RabbitMQ Topology is designed and configured and it independent of the Client Framework that you use.

And if you have multiple consumers , consuming messages from a same queue , they get messages in round robin manner by default.

In your case as you say that in case Instance1 fails to process the message , it should nack the message , in which case the message will be en-queued and will be delivered to the next instance.